# TeamCity Failure Condition for ESLint warnings increases does not stop build (using eslint-teamcity)

Tags: teamcity, eslint

I have a TeamCity step that runs this script:

```json
"teamcity:eslint": eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --format ./node_modules/eslint-teamcity/index.js --max-warnings 0
```

It uses the eslint-teamcity to format the error/warnings linting result.
This is the *package.json* configuration:

```json
  "eslint-teamcity": {
    "reporter": "inspections",
    "report-name": "ESLint Violations",
    "error-statistics-name": "ESLint Error Count",
    "warning-statistics-name": "ESLint Warning Count"
  },
```

I created a test "master" branch with 2 lint warnings and TeamCity "Inspections" shows them:

[image]

I have set this Failure Condition:

[image]

Now, to test it I created a branch with 3 or 4 lint warnings.
I commit it but the build does not fail despite the number of warnings has increased:

[image]

I expect the build to fail.

I've no idea how and where TeamCity store the "inspection" warnings counter for that Failure Condition, so I have no idea how to investigate this unexpected behaviour.
Or, I missed some step/configuration?

TeamCity 2019.2
Failuer Condition code:

```json
        failOnMetricChange {
            metric = BuildFailureOnMetric.MetricType.INSPECTION_WARN_COUNT
            units = BuildFailureOnMetric.MetricUnit.DEFAULT_UNIT
            comparison = BuildFailureOnMetric.MetricComparison.MORE
            compareTo = build {
                buildRule = buildWithTag {
                    tag = "test-master"
                }
            }
            stopBuildOnFailure = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took as example of the Failure Condition another TeamCity project that was checking the tests coverage.
I gave for grant (didn't pay attention) that `tag: master` in the Failure Condition was actually looking at "master" branch for reference.

At the end of the log (many other steps after my try) I finally saw this warning:

> Cannot find Latest build with tag: 'test-master', branch filter: feature/test-warnings to calculate metric 'number of inspection warnings' for branch feature/test-warnings

Still not sure if this means also that the comparison cannot be done on another branch, but this answer my question about Failure Condition not working as expected.